# How to get service price in GetReservationRS

Tags: sabre

```
I have booked a valid available service through Sabre PassengerDetailsRS and booking was successful. But in the GetReservationRS, price of the service is missing. How can we get that price. My GetReservationRQ was as below

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns7:GetReservationRQ xmlns:ns7="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" Version="1.19.0">
  <ns7:Locator>*pnr_number</ns7:Locator>
  <ns7:RequestType>Stateful</ns7:RequestType>
  <ns7:ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="3.2.0">
    <ns7:SubjectAreas>
      <ns7:SubjectArea>PRICE_QUOTE</ns7:SubjectArea>
    </ns7:SubjectAreas>
    <ns7:ViewName>Full</ns7:ViewName>
    <ns7:ResponseFormat>STL</ns7:ResponseFormat>
  </ns7:ReturnOptions>
</ns7:GetReservationRQ>
</soapenv:Body>


And in the response, that service is present which I booked in the booking step. But there is no pricing reference for that service, only the flight total price is present which is service excluded price
```

...    
    
      
        /SPORTING FIREARMS
        WEAP BA NN1 LHRZRH0720N11AUG/SPORTING FIREARMS
      
      
        
          
          
            
              
                
                I
                BA
                
                  110.59
                
                2019-06-16T13:03:00
              
            
                  .      .      .

```
How can I get the price of ode="WEAP" (<or114:FreeText>/SPORTING FIREARMS</or114:FreeText>)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add ReturnOptions->SubjectArea->PRICE_QUOTE in GetReservationRQ

```
    e.g:
    <ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="3.2.0">
            <SubjectAreas>
                <SubjectArea>PRICE_QUOTE</SubjectArea>
            </SubjectAreas>
    </ReturnOptions>

for more details please have a look at below URL (Sabre Documentation)

`https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary`/Retrieve_Itinerary
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, basically I followed as per the documentation which is similar as you mentioned. I added my sample request

Answer (score 0):

I use GetPriceQuoteRQ after GetReservationRQ.
https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/manage_price_quote_details

Answer (score 0):

As this is an upsell for most airlines it falls under ancillary services - therefore to price them you should use: GetAncillaryOffersRQ